# Logstash: parse multiline field for elasticsearch

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

I try to prepare a csv file for elasticsearch. However the csv file has a multiline field in it representing a unstructured text field. For example,

```
id_num,text
1,"bla bla bla
bla bla

bla bla bla"
2, "bla bla
bla"
```

For a csv without multiline field, I know how to deal with, such as

```
input {
    stdin {}
}

filter {
  csv {
    separator => ','
    columns =>  ["id_num","text"]
   }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => 'localhost'
    index_type => "locality"
    flush_size => 1000
    protocol => 'http'
}
```

However, this gave me

```
Unclosed quote
```

error.
Please help!

Comment: I have the same problem. did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the multiline filter

eg

```
filter {
  multiline {
    pattern => "(^.+id_num.+)"
    what => "next"
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Did you mean to add the multiline filter before or after the csv filter or instead?